# How to call a 0-argument function repeatedly and collect the return values into a list using stream/lambda in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

Say I would like to create a "random" list of 100 users by using the `fakeRandomUser` function below.

```
public class User {
    String name;

    static public User fakeRandomUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.name = "foobar";
        return user;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to do this with the Stream API instead of appending to a list in a loop?

Comment: might want to look into `Collections.nCopies` as well

Comment: @Naman `nCopies` seem to repeat a evaluated value, but a function to return value is needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to construct an `IntStream` of 100 items, and map it to your `fakeRandomUser` function:

```
List<User> users = IntStream.range(0, 100)
    .mapToObj(e -> User.fakeRandomUser())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another way is to use [`Stream.generate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-), like so:

```
List<User> users = Stream.generate(User::fakeRandomUser)
    .limit(100)
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: `List<User> users = Stream.generate(() -> User.fakeRandomUser()).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Great suggestion. I'd also note you could use a method reference for the arg to generate: `Stream.generate(User::fakeRandomUser).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());`, I'll add the suggestion

Comment: @ElliottFrisch though `IntStream::generate` will parallelize a lot better than `limit`

Comment: @Eugene Agreed, with random users order is unlikely to matter.